# javafx remove event node.setOnDragDetected

Tags: events, javafx

I got an event on a button and i want to remove this event. How do i do it?

```
button.setOnDragDetected(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
    public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
        /* drag was detected, start a drag-and-drop gesture*/
        /* allow any transfer mode */
        Dragboard db = button.startDragAndDrop(TransferMode.ANY);
    
        /* Put a string on a dragboard */
        ClipboardContent content = new ClipboardContent();
        content.putString(source.getText());
        db.setContent(content);
    
        event.consume();
    }
});
```

Comment: guess i can recreate this button (remove and add again) but if there is a way to remove just the event - i would use it

Comment: Do you mean "remove the event handler"?

Comment: yeah, like it was for just one use and then remove it (just example)

Comment: what's wrong with button.removeListener(this)? or in your case button.setOnDragDetected(null)?

Comment: Thats exactly what i wanted! Thank you. I though there is a different way of removing it, not just a simple null :)